Issue in running spring boot project
I have downloaded a basic spring boot project from spring initializer. But when I am trying to run it it is showing error.




I had tried to change the version maven build version to 17 but still it has not worked.

Don't post links to photo's of code. Include the code as text with proper code tags in your question. We aren't going to click 4 links to get an overview.

Oh my god... you took pictures of the screen with a camera? Please don't ever do that. Copy the original text to your question.

It was first time, will keep it in mind for future.

I believe it's an issue with the language version. Try referring to this article: IntelliJ: Error:java: error: release version 5 not supported
